# Compiler Error while using libusb.h

Tags: c++, libusb-1.0

I am writing a program in QT in C++. I am using the library libusb.h.
Below is my code -

```
libusb_device **devs;
libusb_device_handle *dev_handle;
libusb_context *ctx = NULL;
int r;
ssize_t cnt; 
r = libusb_init(&ctx); 
if(r < 0) {
        cout<<"Init Error "<<r<<endl; //there was an error
        return 1;
    }
```

But when I want to build it, the errors is occur.

> /home/test/main.cpp:12: błąd: undefined reference to `libusb_init'

This is file.pro

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = test
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Can someone help me pointing out the mistake in my code above?

Comment: You need to link to the libusb as well

Comment: `LIBS += -libusb-1.0` should work (not sure)

Comment: `LIBS += -lusb-1.0` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

That's a link error.

Add the following to your project (.pro) file. Do not forget to edit library path and library name according to your own setup.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0"
LIBS += -L"/usr/lib" -l"usb-1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't

```
#include "libusb.h"
```

or

```
#include <libusb.h>
```

Comment: I included two librarys
#include <iostream>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

Comment: Well, not in the source you gave. If you included it then you don't link it. Most libraries are not just their header.

Comment: `undefined reference` indicates a missing library instead of a missing header. But yes, no `include` is given in the question, you're right about that.